# A better way to get accum list?

Tags: elixir

My purpose is to transform a list `[1,2,3,4]` to `[1,3,6,10]` (accumulated list), and found the related function in `Enum` module.

My code is as follows, How to improve it?

```
  def create_accum_list(list) when is_list(list) do
    {_, list_a} =
      List.foldl(list, {0, []}, fn x, {sum, acc} ->
        a = x + sum
        {a, [a | acc]}
      end)

    Enum.reverse(list_a)
  end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly what [`Enum.scan/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#scan/2) does:

```
iex(1)> Enum.scan([1, 2, 3, 4], &+/2)
[1, 3, 6, 10]
iex(2)> Enum.scan([1, 2, 3, 4], 1, &*/2)
[1, 2, 6, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest most efficient function from the standard library would be [`Enum.map_reduce/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#map_reduce/3)

```elixir
Enum.map_reduce([1, 2, 3, 4], 0, fn x, acc -> {acc + x, acc + x} end)
#⇒ {[1, 3, 6, 10], 10}
```

---

I personally prefer to solve such tasks with a home-baked recursion.